# Key Hierarchy and key Encryption

Tags: encryption, keys, key-exchange, key-derivation

If i have two 56-bit DES keys, and I use these two key to encrypt a 256-bit AES key. Like this $K_{AT}$ encrypts $K_{BT}$ and $K_{BT}$ encrypts $K$

What is the effective security of key $K$?

Is it $2 \times 56$ bits?

Can anyone help?

Comment: I think it should be 2^112 possible combinations. Am i right?

Comment: It depends. Who else does $K$ know? If $K$ gets leaked and $K_{AT},K_{BT}$ are static then there's a good chance an attacker can mount a meat-in-the-middle attack on it and break the key in $2^{57}$ time

Comment: @SEJPM the link(http://postimg.org/image/nfbb6lck7/) contains a full picture of the protocol. As the pictures shown, is it still 2^57 times instead of 2^112? Great helps and thank you!

Comment: Are we assuming anything about the attacker's ability to validate the decrypted $K_{BT}$ or $K$ based on their guess of $K_{AT}$?

Comment: Isn't this part of Coursera Cryptography I? I think I filled in 2^56 and the course said I was wrong ... but note that I once scored a point extra by showing that a state exam was incorrect as well :)

Answer (score 2):

The security - assuming you can validate the correctness of $K$ - is 56 bits (not even counting any attacks on DES itself, assuming to test all keys). This is because you can brute force $K_{BT}$ without even looking at $K_{AT}$ in your particular scheme.

**[EDIT]** I'll explain: lets assume that the correctness of the AES key $K$ can be verified by looking at known plaintext / ciphertext pairs. Knowing $K_{BT}$ unlocks the key $K$, which can then be verified. Hence brute forcing $K_{BT}$ is enough to find the right $K$. And $K_{BT}$ has a security level of 56 bits. You can completely ignore $K_{AT}$, it doesn't offer any additional security at all. Minor note: this will cost you at least 5 decrypts (4 DES encrypts or decrypts for retrieving the AES key and one AES encrypt or decrypt to verify correctness).

2 key triple DES on the other hand would at least offer over 80 bit security. So this scheme is certainly not the best option available if you have 112 bits of entropy for your key.

Comment: the link(postimg.org/image/nfbb6lck7) contains a full picture of the protocol. As the pictures shown, is it still 2^57 times instead of 2^112? Great helps and thank you!

Comment: Sorry, I don't get the information in that picture, probably missing too much context.

Comment: I don't mind downvotes but please indicate why.

Comment: @Ricky I never mentioned $2^{57}$ *anywhere*.

Comment: Afaics Maarten nicely answers exactly the question asked. However, the picture indicates a different situation as sketched. To me the link between the picture is also not clear. What is the goal, to obtain $K_{ab}$? In that case in step 3 it is only protected by encryption by $K_{bs}$, giving 56 bits of security.